# filter by ratio of highest to second highest in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

From my data

```
library(data.table); set.seed(42)
dat <- data.table(id=1:6, group=rep(1:2, each=3), value=runif(6))

> dat
   id group     value
1:  1     1 0.9148060
2:  2     1 0.9370754
3:  3     1 0.2861395
4:  4     2 0.8304476
5:  5     2 0.6417455
6:  6     2 0.5190959
```

I would like to identify only those groups where the highest value is larger than 1.2 times the second-highest value. In the example, this is only group 2, as `0.83/0.64>1.2` but `0.94/0.91<1.2.`. Expected output is therefore:

```
> out
   id group     value
1:  4     2 0.8304476
2:  5     2 0.6417455
```

Comment: can there be missing/infinite values in `value`?

Comment: In my case not but the more general a solution, the better for others, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `data.table`, we `order` the data in decreasing order based on `value` and select top 2 rows of groups which is more than the ratio.

```
library(data.table)
dat[order(-value), .SD[1:2][value[1L]/value[2L] > 1.2], by = group]

#   group id        value
#1:     2  4 0.8304476261
#2:     2  5 0.6417455189
```

---

Using `dplyr`, we can `arrange` the dataframe based on `value`, `group_by` `group`, `filter` those groups where ratio is greater than 1.2 and select top 2 rows.

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  arrange(desc(value)) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  filter((value[1L]/value[2L]) > 1.2) %>%
  top_n(2)

#     id group value
#  <int> <int> <dbl>
#1     4     2 0.830
#2     5     2 0.642
```